# Can't access documentation for pathogen plugins

Tags: vimrc, plugin-pathogen

I have these lines in top of .vimrc

```
execute pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
...
```

When I type `:help NERDTree` I receive  `Sorry, help file "/usr/share/vim/doc/help.txt" not found`

I am using **MobaXterm** on Windows.
I tried same `.vimrc` file and `~./.vim` folder structure on Linux and everything works fine.

Comment: Have you ran `:Helptags` as suggested by pathogen's documentation?

Comment: Yes, I don't get anything when run :Helptags from vim. Command stays there when hit Enter.

Comment: `:Helptags` is a pathogen variant of `:helptags` which builds the help document's help tags. Assuming you have everything setup you should now be able to run `:h NERDTree`

Comment: When I run `:helptags` I receive `E471: Argument required`, when run `:h NERDTree`  I get  `Sorry, help file "/usr/share/vim/doc/help.txt" not found.` I understand the concept of pathogen and I think I have good setup because every plugin works well, only documentation is problem. What is command for vim doc?I didnt try that.

Comment: It is `:Helptags`. Note: the uppercase `H`

Comment: I tried both, with lowercase and upercase and nothing

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 7, but I run Mobaxterm with bash shell

Answer (score 1):

Does `"/usr/share/vim/doc/"` exist on your Windows system? Is Vim looking for a path that isn't there?

Comment: `/usr/share/vim` exist but not `doc` folder. I have `/usr/share/vim/vim74/doc`

Comment: You might try running `vim -V` on the command line to get a sense of where your vim is looking for its files. Maybe check out [Config files for the Windows version of VIM](https://davidcraddock.net/2010/01/10/config-files-for-the-windows-version-of-vim/) as a starting point.